# The set $X := [1, 2] \cup [3, 4]$ is not connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am reading Tao's *Analysis II* (third edition).  Awesome book, if a bit lacking on graphical explanation.

On page 36, he gives the definition and an example:

**Definition 2.4.1** (Connected spaces). Let (*X*, *d*) be a metric space. We say that *X* is *disconnected* iff there exist disjoint non-empty open sets *V* and *W* such that $V \cup W = X$. (Equivalently, *X* is disconnected if and only if *X* contains a non-empty proper subset which is simultaneously closed and open.) We say that *X* is *connected* iff it is non-empty and not disconnected.

**Example 2.4.2.** Consider the set $X := [1, 2] \cup [3, 4]$, with the usual metric. This set is disconnected because the sets [1, 2] and [3, 4] are open relative to *X* (why?).

I cannot seem to follow the reasoning for this.  I know it has to do with the boundary points, balls, and relative topology of [1, 2] and [3, 4], but [1, 2] and [3, 4] "look" like closed sets to me (not open sets as is required by the definition).

Any help?

Comment: They’re also open sets in $X$ because $[1,2]=(0.5,2.5)\cap X$ and $[3,4]=(2.5,4.5)\cap X$. So by definition they are open in the relative topology. Or you pick a point $x\in [1,2]. $ Then the open ball $B_1(x)\subset[1,2]$, so they satisfy the open ball definition, too.

Comment: @Nick sounds like an answer to the question.

Comment: An usual mistake when learning topology is thinking that "closed" is the oposite of "open". That's not the case. You discarded the sets been open because they are closed. In this case, $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ are both closed AND open in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openness and closedness depends on the ambient space. In the very common ambient space of the real numbers, $[1,2]$ *is* a non-open closed subset, as there does not exist any $r > 0$ such that we have open balls of radius $r$ such that $1 \in B_r(1) \subseteq [1,2]$. The same is true of $2 \in [1,2] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $3,4 \in [3,4] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

However, for these sets as subspaces of the metric space $(X,d)$, we can see that setting $r = \frac{1}{2}$, we may construct such open balls
$$1 \in B_{\frac{1}{2}}(1) \subseteq [1,2] \subseteq X \qquad \text{and} \qquad 2 \in B_{\frac{1}{2}}(2) \subseteq [1,2] \subseteq X\text{ .}$$
We may also do the same for $3,4 \in [3,4] \subseteq X$. This is because the elements of (for example) $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(1) \setminus [1,2] = (\frac{1}{2}, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ *are simply not elements* of the ambient metric space $(X,d)$.

Thus, in the context of the ambient metric space $X$, the sets $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ are open. They are still closed, as they are still equal to their closures.

A simple Ti*k*Z illustration follows:

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 2):

When we are dealing with metric subspaces like $X$, the notion of something being "relatively open" is exactly equivalent to openness in the subspace.

That is, we have that for instance $[1,2]$ is open in $X$ if it the intersection of some open set in the enveloping space (in this case $\mathbb{R}$) and the subspace. For small $\epsilon$ then, we note $[1,2] = (1 - \epsilon, 2 + \epsilon) \cap X$, and a similar expression for $[3,4]$. Thus each part is open in $X$, and you have disconnectedness as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can agree that in any metric space $(X,d)$, the open balls $B_r(x)$ with radius $r$ centered at $x$ are open. In fact, by *definition* a subset $Y\subseteq X$ of a metric space is open if and only if for every element $x\in Y$, $Y$ contains an open ball centered at that element, which can be shown to be equivalent to the fact that $Y$ is a union of open balls. (Try proving this yourself: One direction is a simple "proof by applying the definitions", and the other direction requires the triangle inequality)

Now we simply need to demonstrate that $[1,2]\cup[3,4]$ is a union of open balls. In fact, it is so almost by definition, since $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ *are* open balls in $[1,2]\cup[3,4]$! Convince yourself by remembering the definition of an open ball: An open ball $B_r(x)$ in a metric space $X$ is the set $B_r(x):=\{y\in X ~|~ d(x,y)<r\}$. And I say $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ are the open balls with radius $1$ centered at $1.5$ and $3.5$, respectively.

Let's see how this can be: The open ball $B_1(1.5)$ in $[1,2]\cup[3,4]$ is the set of all elements in $[1,2]\cup[3,4]$ which are less than 1 removed from $1.5$. Now, all elements of $[1,2]$ are obviously less than $1$ removed from $1.5$. At the same time, *all* the remaining elements of our metric space $[1,2]\cup[3,4]$ are further removed from $1.5$: $3$ is already $1.5$ removed from $1.5$, and all the other elements are even further removed. So they are not in the ball with radius $1$. So this leaves us with $B_1(1.5)=[1,2]$. The argument for $B_1(3.5)=[3,4]$ goes exactly the same. **Note**: Numbers like $2.3$, whose distance to $1.5$ would also be less than $1$, are not part of our metric space, so they are not included in any open balls! Open balls in a metric space contain *only* elements of that specific metric space.

And also for further clarification: Your claim that $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ are closed is not wrong. They are closed, but also open, in other words: clopen. In fact, you yourself write that it is a possible alternative definition for a disconnected space that there exist subsets besides the empty set and the whole space that are clopen. This is because if $X$ is a union of two disjoint, non-empty open subsets $A$ and $B$, then since $A$ is open and $B$ is the complement of $A$ in $X$, $B$ is closed, and likewise $A$ is also closed, so they are both clopen. And on the other hand, if a non-empty subset $A$ besides $X$ itself is clopen, then it is closed and thus its complement is open by definition, so $A$ and its complement are two non-empty open subsets whose union is $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution you may find more intuitive: $[1, 2]$ is a closed set, (this seems intuitively true to you). Its complement, $[3, 4]$ is also closed, which means that $[1, 2]$ must be open. Therefore, $[1, 2]$ is closed, open, and non-trivial, so the space is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

The subspace topology (a.k.a. the topology that defines "relatively open" sets) is defined as follows. Given some topological space $X$ and subset $Y\subseteq X$, the subspace topology $\tau_S$ on $Y$ is given by $\tau_S=\{U\cap Y:U\in(X,\tau)\}$, where $\tau$ denotes the topology on $X$.

Now, a subset $Y\subseteq X$ is disconnected iff there exist disjoint sets $U'$ and $V'$ open in $(Y,\tau_S)$, apart from $Y$ and $\varnothing$, such that $U'\cup V'=Y$. The disjoint condition means $U'\cap V'=\varnothing$.

In your example, we note that $[1,2]\cup[3,4]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. (I will use the definition $Y=[1,2]\cup[3,4]$) Thus, they will inherit the subspace topology endowed by the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (where open sets are defined in the real analysis sense). The set $(0, 2.5)$ is open in the topology on $\mathbb{R}$, thus, $Y\cap(0,2.5)=[1,2]$ is open in the subspace topology on $Y$ (i.e., $[1,2]$ is relatively open in $Y$). Now, $(2.5,5)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so $Y\cap(2.5,5)=[3,4]$ is open in the subspace topology on $Y$. But notice that $(Y\cap(0,2.5))\cap(Y\cap(2.5,5))=[1,2]\cap[3,4]=\varnothing$ and $(Y\cap(0,2.5))\cup(Y\cap(2.5,5))=[1,2]\cup[3,4]=Y$. Thus, we have found two disjoint sets open in the subspace topology on $Y$, different from $Y$ and $\varnothing$, such that their union is $Y$, so $Y$ must be disconnected.

$\blacksquare$